# Is it quicker to AddRange then look for duplicates or check for clashes on each item?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios

*(note: I have labelled this C# but I am using Monotouch, so it might behave differently, I'm not too sure)*

Here is my scenario:
I have a List which persists throughout my app, this holds onto an entire list of objects. I then filter this data (via user choices in the app) and display the appropriate items.

The list gets updated by a call to the webservice, the way I do this is as follows:

```
HandleWebServiceComplete(object sender, ItemRetreivedEventArgs e)
{
    // snip - error handling above this

    if (e.Result != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.Result)
        {
            if (!mainList.Contains(item))
                mainList.Add(item);
        }

        RefreshDisplayList(mainList);
    }
}
```

So obviously this checks every single item returned by the web service, to check that it doesn't already exist in the list (there are situations where it could) - so my question is, would it be better to use `List.AddRange()` then check for duplicates in the list afterwards or just carry on the way I'm going already?

Comment: profile it both ways and find out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I definitely would not AddRange and then remove duplicates, as each removal will trigger a rebuild of the backing array. The way you are doing it is fine. I presume you are not actually having performance issues currently.

Comment: Due to the fact am working with limited memory & processing power, just looking at ways I could generally keep memory + proc. power down - thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Luke If you AddRange and then eliminate duplicates, you will have to scan the range roughly for each item you have added, so you gain nothing in CPU, and if you then remove elements then you face a CPU and memory penalty as you will indirectly rebuid the backing array each time (although the wasted memory will eventually be reclaimed). What you are already doing has a space-time balance. Your options are to go in either direction, not reduce both. There is an easy time optimisation, if you are willing to potentially lose memory - use a dictionary.

Comment: @Luke Actually, look at a HashSet.

Comment: @ as you do not need to store keys and values. Still less memory efficient than a list, but duplicate lookup will be much faster.

Comment: I am now using a HashSet and it has given a slight, but noticable, performance boost when there are a lot of messages (and a higher chance of duplicates) - many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're not interested into the order of the items you can just use an HashSet<> instead of List<>. The `UnionWith()` method accept a "range" and will do just what you want.

Comment: Another option (if order is important) is to keep two data structures: one that keeps the order (the current list) and one that is used to determine whether the object is there or not (a HashSet or a Dictionary).